# Grails DataSource Encryption Error

Tags: grails, encryption, groovy

I'm trying to encrypt the database password in the DataSource.groovy file.
I'm following these directions: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3620

I've written a class to encode/decode and ***it works fine when I am debugging from my development machine***.  But the web server (using the same Database and same url, username, password) gives me the following error when I deploy it:

```
ERROR] 2013-12-06 08:52:15,367 (StackTrace:sanitize:260) | Sanitizing stacktrace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: bad character in base64 value
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.EncodingGroovyMethods.decodeBase64(EncodingGroovyMethods.java:177)
```

---

Encoding class:

```
import java.security.*
import javax.crypto.*
import javax.crypto.spec.*

public class Des {
    static encode = { String target ->
        def cipher = getCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE)
        return cipher.doFinal(target.bytes).encodeBase64()
    }

    static decode = { String target ->
        println "DECODE TARGET :::: " + target
        def cipher = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE)
        def b64Char = target.decodeBase64()
        println "BASE64 CHAR :::: " + b64Char
        def ret = cipher.doFinal(b64Char)
        println "DECODE VALUE :::" + ret
        return ret
    }

    private static getCipher(mode) {
        def keySpec = new DESKeySpec(getKeySecretKey())
        def cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES")
        def keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES")
        cipher.init(mode, keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec))
        return cipher
    }

    private static getKeySecretKey() {
        "MySecret1234".getBytes("UTF-8")
    }

    static void main(args) {
        println encode("TheP4ssword")
    }
}
```

DataSource.groovy snippet

```
dashboard_dev {
    dataSource {
        url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server:1433;databaseName=dbName"
        username = "UserDashboard"
        password=Des.decode("j123456789nYmRLN4ziyJw==")
        // Not needed -- passwordEncryptionCodec = com.rdc.encryption.Des
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the issue is with `def b64Char = target.decodeBase64()`, but I can't see what's wrong with it...  Is the `"j123456789nYmRLN4ziyJw=="` value exactly the same in dev and production?

Comment: Might be worth changing the last line of `encode` to `return cipher.doFinal(target.bytes).encodeBase64().toString()` as it currently returns a `Writable` (so `decode( encode("TheP4ssword") )` doens't work)

Comment: The password is getting encoded and decoded correctly when I step though the code.  @tim_yates, the values are the same in both environments and they are pointing to the same database.