# Attempting to encrypt datasource password in owfConfig.groovy of Ozone Widget Framework

Tags: tomcat, encryption, groovy

I am trying to encrypt the datasource password in owfConfig.groovy.

I tried encrypting the password following a process for encrypting passwords in tomcat ( http://www.jdev.it/encrypting-passwords-in-tomcat/ ).  I run through all steps outlined in these instructions and successfully generate an encoded password.  I added a 'Factory' attribute to owfConfig.groovy pointing to my encryptionFactory and defined the password to be my encrypted password.  It doesn't look like the 'Factory' attribute is interpreted when starting the server.  I get the following exception:

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'owfadmin'@'myserver.address' (using password: YES))

I'm unable to find a list of parameters allowed in the owfConfig.groovy file so 'Factory' was kind of a shot in the dark.

I have also checked out the threads: [is-it-possible-to-encrypt-datasource-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960350/is-it-possible-to-encrypt-datasource-properties) and [grails-datasource-encryption-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425824/grails-datasource-encryption-error), but neither of these seem to apply to what I'm trying to do

any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I needed to search a little more.  There is a patch available on owfgoss.org to handle this very issue.

You just need to use the patch to encrypt the password and add a definition for passwordEncryptionCodec in the owfConfig.groovy file.

hopefully this will help somebody searching for the same solution

The patch can be found [here](https://owfgoss.org/svn/repos/ozone/downloads/Patches/owf-server/OWFPATCHES-37/).